# show() fragment occasionally doesn't add it the FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

Sometimes, when I do the following :

```
fragment = (LoadingFragment) Fragment.instantiate(activity, className);
fragment.setCancelable(false);
fragment.show(fragmentManager, TAG);
```

the LoadingFragment is shown in the fargmentManager, but sometimes it is not - and 
`fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG)` would just return null.

I don't understand the inconsistency.. anybody got a clue?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the `Fragment.instantiate()` directly. That might be your problem. I think you want:

```
LoadingFragment fragment = new LoadingFragment();
fragment.setCancelable(false);
fragment.show(fragmentManager,TAG);
```